# "Expanding" a reflexive Many to Many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

Using Elixir 0.7.1 and SQLAlchemy 0.7.8, I've created a model having a many-to-many relationship back to itself, which looks like:

```
from elixir import *

class MyModel(Entity):
    name = Field(Unicode(30))
    related = ManyToMany('MyModel')
```

Now, if I have some arbitrary query on these, say

```
q1 = MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.name.like("%Bob%"))
```

Then I want to build a separate query that will return the flat list of distinct MyModel objects that are related to any of the objects in `q1`. That is, if I had

```
q1.all() == [m1, m2, m3]
```

Then I want a query `q2` (probably with `q1` as a subquery) which will return a flat list consisting of the union of `m1.related`, `m2.related`, and `m3.related`. This is easy to do if I just execute `q1` first and then drop down to Python list manipulation for the rest, but it seems like there should be a faster way when `q1` returns many objects. Any thoughts on how to do this? Should I be using some sort of join on/with the intermediary table generated by Elixir for the many-to-many relationship?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a simple solution without having to explicitly reference the join table:

```
q2 = MyModel.query.join(q1.subquery(), MyModel.related)
```